# Identifying users without cookies etc

Tags: node.js, session, cookies

I want to write a new aggregator site where users can submit news and up and down vote on them (Pretty basic stuff, similar to a tiny reddit).

My problem is this:

- Someone can only up or downvote a news article once a day
- I don't want users so sign up
- Cookies for voting could be deleted

How do i identify a user over the course of the day and how do i make sure that this user didn't vote on some article some minutes before.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Without logins; you dont. Period. Even with logins, it's very difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the **browser fingerprint**.

The *browser fingerprint* is an identifier generated from the information that every browser sends on every connection (HTTP headers) and additional information available through basic JavaScript.

Information like:

- User agent
- Language
- Installed plugins
- Screen resolution
- ... and more.

A *browser fingerprint identification* isn't bulletproof because there are [self-defense tactics](https://panopticlick.eff.org/self-defense.php) but it can spice up your recipe. Despite its controversy, it's [widely used](http://www.examiner.com/article/top-internet-sites-use-browser-fingerprinting-to-secretly-track-users).

Mozilla has a [great wiki article about the subject](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Fingerprinting).

And you can check your own browser fingerprint at https://panopticlick.eff.org/

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, it is not possible to reliably identify a user without login and without using cookies *or a similar technique*.

I hate to post this, but the [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) project is a good collection of the techniques for making something like a cookie that is somewhat more persistent than your standard cookie. It uses some neat tricks, but one could also argue that it has some privacy issues. I would not recommend you to implement it. Even if you did (or borrow some of their ideas), then

- Any remotely tech-savvy user would still be able to clear the cookie.
- You can't guard against users using multiple devices and browsers.
- You can't (reliably) guard against users not posting via a browser, thus circumventing cookies and other tricks.
- Etc, etc.

Comment: And the amount of time us mods spend daily tracking down sock-puppet voters shows it's very difficult even with logins.